# why are the end points of a closed function local extremums when they are not critical points?

Tags: calculus

Fermat's theorem says that all local extremum has to occur at critical points. For example, if f(c) is a local extremum, then x=c has to be a critical point. A critical point c is defined as f'(c)=0 or f'(c) is undefined I saw in some notes that the end points of a closed interval function are also local extremums.
An example would be f(x)=x^3 where x lies in [-3,3]. In this case, f(-3) is a local minimum and f(3) is a local maximum but why are they considered critical points? f'(3) and f'(-3) is neither 0 nor undefined.

Comment: I think it have to be local extremum if it is an interior point as the proof of the local minimum and maximum with derivative require $c$ to be an interior point

Comment: The notion of local extrema is for points which are interior to the interval and not for end points.

Comment: The end-points can be global extrema.